# Multiple File Uploader Java

Tags: java, file, upload, uploader

I've created a program to upload images from one device to another. As it stands, the program only allows the user to upload one file at a time. If I wanted to edit the program to allow the user to upload several files at once, what would be the best way of doing it.

```
String source1 = source.getSelectedFile().getPath();
System.out.println("Source1: " + source1);
String nwdir1 = nwdir.getSelectedFile().getPath() + "\\" + filename;
System.out.println("nwdir1: " + nwdir1);

Path source = Paths.get(source1);
Path nwdir = Paths.get(nwdir1);

try {
    Files.copy(source, nwdir);
```

I've noticed you can do .getSelectedFiles(), but as that doesn't allow .getPath() im unsure how to continue. Assuming you can do this:

```
File[] source1 = source.getSelectedFiles();
```

How would I go about doing the second line:

```
String nwdir1 = nwdir.getSelectedFile().getPath() + "\\" + filename;
```

When I replace the line with the File array (shown above), I get an error on lines:

```
Path source = Paths.get(source1);
Path nwdir = Paths.get(nwdir1);
```

Comment: Why don't you just let the user specify multiple files, and then load them all at once?

Comment: That was the idea. But i'm not 100% sure how to do that. At the moment, it loads the directory but only allows the user to select one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File.listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) or [File.listFiles(FileFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29)

**Multi file selection**

Sorry, that's what I thought you wanted, but you're using the `JFileChooser` to select a directory so I assumed you want to do a directory listing :P

Set the `JFileChooser` to allow multiple selections using [setMultiSelectionEnabeld](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled%28boolean%29). You'll probably want to set the file selection mode to `JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY` or `JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES` if you still want them to be able to select directories.

You will probably also want to set the file filter to allow the dialog to filter the directories contents, restricting what the user can select, for simplicity sake, take a look at [FileNameExtensionFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html)

**UPDATED**

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "png", "jpg", "jpeg");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

switch (chooser.showOpenDialog(null)) {

    case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:

        String currentPath = chooser.getCurrentDirectory().getPath();
        File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

        if (files.length > 0) {

            System.out.println("You have choosen " + files.length + " from " + currentPath);

        } else {

            System.out.println("You didn't selected anything");

        }

        break;

}
```

Comment: Could you show me an example of this working? Just attempting to code it now. All that seems to do is list the files in a directory? I've managed to code it to show the list of files in a directory. Im just not sure how the user can select certain files.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I've added the line source.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

This does allow me to select several files, but only one is sent? I've taken a look but cant work it out.

Comment: @AdamHinx Use `getSelectedFiles()` instead of `getSelectedFile()` it will return an array of the selected files

Comment: Hmmm. I did have that already. Still only copying one image. I've edited original post with source code. Please note that I know the throw catch isn't the best way of doing it. I'm cleaning up the code later. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AdamHinx no where in your code do seem to be using `getSelectedFiles` (not the "s" on the end).  You're only using the `getSelectedFile` method.  The first returns an array of `File`s the other returns a single `File`

Comment: I did change it, but several lines had errors.    String path = source.getSelectedFiles().getPath();
            File[] file = source.getSelectedFiles();
            filename = source.getName(file);

Comment: @AdamHinx `getSelectedFiles()` returns an **ARRAY** of `File`.  You can't simply ask for the path because array doesn't have that method. If you really want to know the current path use `JFileChooser.getCurrentDirectory()` instead!

Comment: The reason for .getPath is to return a string

Comment: `source.getCurrentDirectory().getPath()` you could use the array of files but this is just simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your patient MadProgrammer. I'm new to programming. I've edited my original question to update where I'm at. I didn't think it would be this complicated to create such feature.

Comment: @AdamHinx I've updated my example with a simple example of what you seem to be trying to achieve.

Comment: Madprogrammer, that makes much more sense. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AdamHinx Picture paints a thousand words ;)

Comment: MadProgrammer, I've taken a better look into the program you pasted yesterday. My program already allows me to select more than one file, my program is sending it. As before, I use Files.copy(source, nwdir). But as source is now an array, it wont support it?

Comment: @AdamHinx you have to choices, you will either need to update the file copy code to work with arrays, or call the method multiple times from a loop

Answer (score 1):

Use FileUtils from apache commons library. Very powerful and useful. You can even specify which file formats you want to copy etc.